# How many vlans we can create in one single port

Tags: vlan

May I know how many vlans can be create and configure in single port and we can access in switch???

If we create the vlan and if we assigned one port to particular vlan, I thought that should be works under one vlan and if possible means how many max we can create and how to configure?

Comment: A trunked port can handle as many VLANs you can create on the switch. Typically up to 4094 VLANs.

Comment: That actually depends on the device model. Theoretically, you could create all VLANs, but some devices have a limit, e.g. 250 VLANs, even though your VLAN numbers can be any valid VLAN number.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Often, a given device has a hardware limit of e.g. 512 VLANs.

With 802.1q tagging, the absolute limit is 4,094 (the tag is 12 bit in size and VIDs 0 and 4,095 are reserved).

With 801.1aq tagging, the tag (SPBV) is expanded to 24 bit, so 16 million VIDs are possible.

When trunking between devices you can have a single VLAN untagged, all others need to be tagged.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a port as an access-port, only one VLAN can be assigned to this port.

If you want to use a port as a trunk though, all VLANs which can be handled by the switch can be "assigned" (You don't need to assign VLANs to a trunk because per default, it will handle every VLAN). This number of VLANs can go from 0-4095 but 0 and 4095 are reserved - so they should not be used. So 1-4094.

As @RonMaupin pointed out, some devices have a lower limit (f.i. 250).

More information about how they work, what they do and how to configure them can be found [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus5000/sw/configuration/guide/cli/CLIConfigurationGuide/VLANs.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make Port as access Port you can configure single vlan

If you want to configure Port as trunk Port you can configure allowed vlan or multiple vlans or all vlans

Answer (score -3):

You can create multiple VLANs on the Switch. By default, you can assign One Access Vlan (Data) and One Voice vlan on the switch port.

Comment: That's not quite correct.  A Cisco access port with a voice VLAN is really a trunk port.  Really, any port with a tagged VLAN is a trunk port.  Other manufacturers use different terms for the same thing..